# PHP Fatal error while updating the UUID

Tags: drush

I am getting the following error while updating the UUID with `sudo drush config-set "system.site" uuid "d523bcdf-9d4b-45f4-9acc-a97ba4889b66"` on Drupal 8.2.x.

> PHP Fatal error: Class Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle contains 4 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface::isQuiet, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface::isVerbose, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface::isVeryVerbose, ...) in /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Style/SymfonyStyle.php on line 33
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   Error: Class Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle contains 4 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface::isQuiet, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface::isVerbose, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface::isVeryVerbose, ...) in /var/www/html/drupal/vendor/symfony/console/Style/SymfonyStyle.php, line 33

How do I fix this error?